# Cordova app crashing in Samsung

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, galaxy, crash-log

I have developed a cordova app that runs fine in emulator, but when I try it on physical devices, a critical exception causes the app to abort on Samsung Galaxy. The app crashes before I could even see the first screen. The crash log is as follows.

```
Activity com.englishdynamo.idiomApp2.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopWebContentsAccessibility$1@XXXXXX that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.englishdynamo.idiomApp2.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopWebContentsAccessibility$1@XXXXXX that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java)
at org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopWebContentsAccessibility.<init>(LollipopWebContentsAccessibility.java:3)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.getAccessibilityNodeProvider(WebViewChromium.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.getAccessibilityNodeProvider(WebView.java)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of information here but when I have had applications crash immediately it has been because I have built for the wrong architecture.

Make sure the architecture you are building for is correct. The emulator is likely to be different to the device.